# Wifi Network Request Api connection issue in android 10 (Q)

Tags: android, android-10.0

i am trying to add network using android [Wifi Network Request Api](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-bootstrap) every thing is going fine its showing dialog for connect to my given network and click on connect callback [onAvailable()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback#onAvailable(android.net.Network)) method also called but it waits for some time and then after its switch back to last connected network which having internet

[App video Link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=10QR3vK3kg3HuWPupNGNoSTPa1BL7dzuf)

Comment: First, make sharable link and open for all for video.

Comment: thanks , its in drive processing will be available soon

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56831023/android-q-programmatically-connect-to-different-wifi-ap-for-internet

Answer (score 3):

I know it is very late to answer but maybe someone helps.

You have to bind your network to the connection.

```
@Override
 public void onAvailable(Network network)
 {
    try
    {
        super.onAvailable(network);
        if (SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.M)
        { manager.bindProcessToNetwork(network);
        }
        else
        { ConnectivityManager.setProcessDefaultNetwork(network);
        }
        ...
```

Comment: This was the missing call. Google never document this stuff either.