# WiFi Network Connection keeps disconnecting on Android Q

Tags: android, android-10.0, android-connectivitymanager

I use the [WiFi Network Request API](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-bootstrap) to connect to a network on android Q. The connection becomes available but gets lost.
Here is my code

```
           public void registerNetworkCallback() {
        try {
            ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            WifiNetworkSpecifier specifier = new WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder()
                    .setSsid("r_guest").setWpa2Passphrase("guest").build();


            NetworkRequest networkRequest = new NetworkRequest.Builder()
                    .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
                    .removeCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)
                    .addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_NOT_RESTRICTED)
                    .addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_TRUSTED)
                    .setNetworkSpecifier(specifier)
                    .build();
            NetworkRequest.Builder builder = new NetworkRequest.Builder();

            connectivityManager.requestNetwork(networkRequest, new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAvailable(Network network) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "ConnectivityManager onAvailable");
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onLost(Network network) {

                            Log.d(TAG, "ConnectivityManager onLost");
                        }
            );

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
```

I already tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58947697/3604786) and I also came across the posts [like this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58534668/wifi-network-request-api-connection-issue-in-android-10-q)

These is the log that NetworkCallBack throws:

```
2020-01-17 13:51:24.895 ConnectivityManager available
2020-01-17 13:51:24.896 ConnectivityManager onCapabilitiesChanged 1071 [ Transports: WIFI Capabilities: 

NOT_METERED&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VPN&NOT_ROAMING&FOREGROUND&NOT_CONGESTED&NOT_SUSPENDED LinkUpBandwidth>=1048576Kbps LinkDnBandwidth>=1048576Kbps SignalStrength: -47]
2020-01-17 13:51:24.897 ConnectivityManager onLinkPropertiesChanged 1071 {InterfaceName: wlan0 LinkAddresses: [ fe80::189e:ebff:fead:5f9d/64,192.168.1.57/24 ] DnsAddresses: [ /192.168.1.1,/8.8.8.8 ] Domains: null MTU: 0 TcpBufferSizes: 524288,1048576,4194304,524288,1048576,4194304 Routes: [ fe80::/64 -> :: wlan0,192.168.1.0/24 -> 0.0.0.0 wlan0,0.0.0.0/0 -> 192.168.1.1 wlan0 ]}
2020-01-17 13:51:24.897 ConnectivityManager onBlockedStatusChanged false
2020-01-17 13:51:24.935 ConnectivityManager onCapabilitiesChanged 1071 [ Transports: WIFI Capabilities: NOT_METERED&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VPN&VALIDATED&NOT_ROAMING&FOREGROUND&NOT_CONGESTED&NOT_SUSPENDED LinkUpBandwidth>=1048576Kbps LinkDnBandwidth>=1048576Kbps SignalStrength: -47]
2020-01-17 13:51:24.976 ConnectivityManager onLost
```

I would appreciate any ideas?

Comment: Hi, did you ever figure this out?

Comment: still searching :(

Comment: did you find answer?