# Connecting to specific network - Android 10 - Java

Tags: java, android, android-10.0

I'm developing an app which needs to connect to a specific wifi network with internet capabilities. My app targets Android 10 devices and I'm writting it in java. I took inspiration from this post: https://blog.ostebaronen.dk/2019/11/android-10-wifi.html (Thanks @Cheesebaron).

I can't find a suitable java translation (line or set of lines in java programming language) for the next line

```
NetworkAvailable?.Invoke(network);
```

which connects the device. The Invoke method is called in the OnAvailable method.

```
final ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback networkCallback =
        new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onAvailable(@NonNull Network network) {
                super.onAvailable(network);
                // connect to network
                Log.i(TAG, "Connected to network with WIFI capabilities");
            }
            ...
        };
```

(I've include the necessary permissions in android manifest)

Comment: What do you mean "java translation"? Translation from what? What do you mean by "connecting to a specific network"? Do you mean a Wifi connection? Do you mean a VPN connection?

Comment: By java translation I mean a line in java programming language.
By connecting to a specific network I mean connecting to a specific wifi network with internet capabilities.
I'll edit the post, thanks for suggesting them

Comment: Ok, I didn't check the link you mentioned, sorry. You want a translation from C#. NetworkAvailable is an Action; in Java this corresponds to [a lambda expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html).

Comment: I see. But is there a way to connect the device directly to the only network I specified (skipping the UI)?

Answer (score 1):

Accoording to this comment: [Android Q, programmatically connect to different WiFi AP for internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56831023/android-q-programmatically-connect-to-different-wifi-ap-for-internet#comment113081832_61282870)

If I need internet capabilities, a WifiNetworkSuggestion is required